# constructibility for pushforward

Tags: etale-cohomology, schemes, sheaf-cohomology, constructible-sheaves

Let consider a quasicompact open $j:U\rightarrow\mathbb{A}^{\mathbb{N}}$ over a field $k$, Is there an example where $Rj_{*}\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is not constructible, where $n$ is prime to the characteristic?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by $\mathbb{A}^{\mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: $\varprojlim\mathbb{A}^{n}$

Comment: With what transition maps?

Comment: first projection

Comment: Okay, in that case, for every quasi-compact open $U$, there exists finite $n$ and an open $U_n \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ such that $U$ is the inverse image of $U_n$ under projection from $\mathbb{A}^{\mathbb{N}}$ to $\mathbb{A}^n$.  There is a smooth base change theorem for constructible sheaves . . .